# libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

Tags: c++, textures, sdl2

I was working with SDL2 and when I loaded some textures, I got this warning in the console ***libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile*** 
Though this doesn't cause any error, everything works fine but I just wanted to know what this warning is about.
[image: GuitarMan.png]

This is the picture I'm trying to load, maybe the fault is in the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a warning that can be safely ignored. If you want to remove it you have to remove the iCCP chunk from the image. You should be able to do this with any image editing program. For example if you're using `ImageMagick` you could do something like `convert your-image-name.png some-other-name.png`. Here's a [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2kzj38/tool_for_removing_the_warning_libpng_warning_iccp/) about removing the warning as well.